# How to get through restrictions blocking OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, security, firewall, openvpn

I have recently set up a VPN server on my desktop at home in the hopes I can connect to it while at the university from my laptop. I have confirmed that I can connect easily on a mobile data hotspot, but I'm unable to at the university. This is almost certainly due to them blocking the connection (as they do to almost all VPN providers either I or my friends have tried).

To get around this I have:

- Used TCP protocol
- Used port 443
- Used SSL encryption (I think - this wasn't done deliberately but when following a guide to set up the server it seems I did this, when I was looking into setting it up the instructions were all things I had already done such as generating certificates and CA files).

When I try to connect, I cannot get any connection at all. I can't check the server logs whilst I'm not at home, but I think based on the third message below that it would show a connection instantaneously. The client server logs have a few lines which jump out to me:

```
SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting 

Connection reset, restarting [-1]

TCP connection established with [AF_INET]XX.XXX.X.XX:443
```

I have also looked into obfuscation techniques, but was told that although it could help against a manual inspection, it would be useless into an automated process which this almost certainly is.

Do I have any other relatively simple methods I can use to solve this?

Also bear in mind that I am relatively knowledgeable compared to the average person on networking and VPNs, but not at all knowledgeable compared to many people on this forum (setting up the VPN server took about 10 hours of set up and bug fixing).

I found a way to view the server logs, and I can confirm that when I try to connect from the client the server sees the connection and gets the same `sigusr1` reset message.

As requested, here is the client log for verb 3 before the `sigusr1` message:

```
2024-02-06 11:37:11 us=843000 MANAGEMENT: STATE:1707219431,RECONNECTING,connection-reset,,,,,
2024-02-06 11:37:11 us=843000 Restart pause, 1 second(s)
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 Re-using SSL/TLS context
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 Control Channel MTU parms [ mss_fix:0 max_frag:0 tun_mtu:1250 tun_max_mtu:0 headroom:126 payload:1600 tailroom:126 ET:0 ]
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 Data Channel MTU parms [ mss_fix:0 max_frag:0 tun_mtu:1500 tun_max_mtu:1600 headroom:136 payload:1768 tailroom:562 ET:0 ]
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XX.XXX.X.XXX:433
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]XX.XXX.X.XXX:433
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=859000 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1707219432,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=890000 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]XX.XXX.X.XXX:433
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=890000 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=890000 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]XX.XXX.X.XXX:433
2024-02-06 11:37:12 us=890000 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1707219432,WAIT,,,,,,
2024-02-06 11:37:13 us=140000 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
2024-02-06 11:37:13 us=171000 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
2024-02-06 11:37:13 us=171000 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
```

Comment: SIGUSR1 is not a network message – it's an internal signal sent between processes, in this case OpenVPN raising it to itself, which it does in response to _something else_ that happened a few lines earlier. What's in the logs (of both the server and the client) if you run them with `verb 3` or `verb 4` for more details?

Comment: I cant get the server logs on verb 4 for a few hours, but ive added the client logs to the post. Hope that helps.

Comment: Right, so at "Connection reset" it most likely gets a TCP RST from the network (presumably from the university's network firewall).

Comment: Thats what i assumed - is there anything i can do to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

> Used SSL encryption (I think - this wasnt done deliberately but when following a guide to set up the server it seems I did this, when i was looking into setting it up the instructions were all things i had already done such as generating certificates and ca files).

OpenVPN always uses TLS. However, unlike everything else, it uses TLS *inside* its own OpenVPN protocol, so it will still remain easily recognizable as OpenVPN. (That is, you have an "OpenVPN" connection with a TLS-based control channel and a non-TLS data channel multiplexed together.)

If you actually need it to *look like* TLS, then:

- You could use `stunnel` (on both sides) to tunnel any TCP-based protocol inside TLS.
- You could also look for alternative VPN protocols – specifically, I would suggest OpenConnect (with `ocserv` on the server) because it is 1) entirely TLS-based and 2) exactly the same as the Cisco AnyConnect protocol frequently used for corporate VPNs, so it will "blend in" as a workplace VPN. (In fact, ocserv even accepts real Cisco AnyConnect clients.)
- Another similar choice would be SSTP, which is Microsoft's take on "TLS VPN" – the client is built-in to Windows.

If you're able to use SSH, the Linux version of OpenSSH supports being used as a VPN tunnel (the `-w` option).

Comment: Ok thanks - im trying to set up stunnel but im on a windows machine, do you know if thats then required on both sides?

Comment: Yes, because it's changing the protocol in a way that the regular OpenVPN server won't recognize, so you need to do the opposite on the server (in stunnel's case, different accept= mode). Kinda like how you need both the web browser _and_ the web server to support HTTPS.

Comment: Do you know of any places i can get some documentation on how to install and configure stunnel on the server? I've got it working on the client (i think), and have found plenty of guides for that e.g https://www.securevpn.pro/eng/setup/stealth-vpn-windows , but i cant find anything to set it up on the server.

Comment: It's mostly the same except with client=no (making it strip TLS instead of adding it), and with cert=/key= specified for TLS.

Comment: Ill try and set that up, but i recently talked to my compsci professor who said that the university were probably just blocking all ip addresses belonging to residences. He had tried to setup a vpn and obfuscate it a while ago and failed. Would there be a way to get around it if the university were doing that?

Comment: If they block residential addresses, rent a cheap VPS and set up a VPN there – then you'll have it at a "datacenter" address; connecting the VPS to your home network will take another VPN but probably easier on the whole than dealing with weird firewalls here. It leaves me incredibly confused as to *why* a university would be doing that, though.

Comment: Ok, thats another option i can look into. They do it because they have a policy against using any vpns on their network.